# laravel how to access column with number name of a table?

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, object

I make a table with number 22 as the column name. How to access this column?

[image]

content:

[image]

I've tryed thest

```
$obj = Tablename::find(1)->first();
$obj->22;
$obj->'22';   //'syntax error, unexpected ''22''
$obj->"22";
$obj->`22`;
$obj[22];
$arr = $obj->toArray();
var_dump($arr); //  array(15) { ["id"]=> string(2) "25" ["out_trade_no"]=> string(14) "14847080930025" ["22"]=> string(0) "2"
$arr[22];       // 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 22'
$arr['22'];     // 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 22'
$arr["22"];     // 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 22'
$arr[`22`];     // 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: ' in
$arr[{'22'}];   //  'syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'' in
```

none works.

edited as the answer implemented: also get null.

```
var_dump($orders[0]);
var_dump($orders[0]->id);
var_dump($orders[0]->{'22'});
$col = '22';
$res = $orders[0]->{$col};
var_dump($res);
```

output:

```
object(Order)#537(21){
    [
        "connection": protected
    ]=>NULL[
        "table": protected
    ]=>NULL[
        "primaryKey": protected
    ]=>string(2)"id"[
        "perPage": protected
    ]=>int(15)[
        "incrementing"
    ]=>bool(true)[
        "timestamps"
    ]=>bool(true)[
        "attributes": protected
    ]=>array(15){
        [
            "id"
        ]=>string(2)"25"[
            "out_trade_no"
        ]=>string(14)"14847080930025"[
            "22"
        ]=>string(1)"2"[
            "user_id"
        ]=>string(2)"49"[
            "product_name"
        ]=>string(4)"test"[
            "amount"
        ]=>string(1)"3"[
            "fee"
        ]=>string(4)"0.03"[
            "address_id"
        ]=>string(1)"3"[
            "trade_status"
        ]=>string(13)"TRADE_SUCCESS"[
            "express_name"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "express_no"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "buyer_email"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "modify_at"
        ]=>string(19)"2017-01-18 10:54:53"[
            "created_at"
        ]=>string(19)"2017-01-18 10:54:53"[
            "updated_at"
        ]=>string(19)"2017-01-18 10:55:26"
    }[
        "original": protected
    ]=>array(15){
        [
            "id"
        ]=>string(2)"25"[
            "out_trade_no"
        ]=>string(14)"14847080930025"[
            "22"
        ]=>string(1)"2"[
            "user_id"
        ]=>string(2)"49"[
            "product_name"
        ]=>string(4)"test"[
            "amount"
        ]=>string(1)"3"[
            "fee"
        ]=>string(4)"0.03"[
            "address_id"
        ]=>string(1)"3"[
            "trade_status"
        ]=>string(13)"TRADE_SUCCESS"[
            "express_name"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "express_no"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "buyer_email"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "modify_at"
        ]=>string(19)"2017-01-18 10:54:53"[
            "created_at"
        ]=>string(19)"2017-01-18 10:54:53"[
            "updated_at"
        ]=>string(19)"2017-01-18 10:55:26"
    }[
        "relations": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "hidden": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "visible": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "appends": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "fillable": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "guarded": protected
    ]=>array(1){
        [
            0
        ]=>string(1)"*"
    }[
        "dates": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "touches": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "observables": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "with": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
        "morphClass": protected
    ]=>NULL[
        "exists"
    ]=>bool(true)[
        "softDelete": protected
    ]=>bool(false)
}string(2)"25"NULLNULL
```

Edit: acording to [Paras's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330167/6521116)

[image]

Edit2: 
to make question simple and clear:

migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Test extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tests', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('22');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Test extends Eloquent
{
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $tests = Test::all();
    foreach($tests as $test)
    {
        Log::info($test->id);
        Log::info($test->{'22'});
        Log::info($test->{"22"});
        Log::info($test->getAttribute("22"));
    }
}
```

data table:

[image]

and the log:

```
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO: 1 [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO: 2 [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-25 09:16:48] production.INFO:  [] []
```

Comment: The only thing you didn't try: `->{'22'}`

Comment: @Marty will you explain it more, what's the issue here, or where i can refer to ? thank you very much.

Comment: Any reason it has to be called `22`?
The quickest fix, and the best solution, would be to rename it as a string indicating what it is

Comment: @WebKenth I agree with you here.  I just find a substitute way when I've no possibility to modify the database table.  Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is NOT to use Integer as a fieldname. It is bad praxis.
But if you need, you should access the database with raw method:

```
public function show()
{
     $tests = DB::table('test')
        ->select("22 as twentytwo")
        ->get();
    foreach($tests as $test){
        Log::info($test->twentytwo);
    }
}
```

Comment: like a charm, it works. Your answer later, but do the tricks. Thank you.

Comment: that's not a raw method, a raw method uses `DB::raw()`

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following syntax, as found in the [variable variables topic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in the PHP documentation:

```
$obj->{'22'};
```

> ...
>
> **Curly braces may also be used**, to clearly delimit the property name. They are most useful when accessing values within a property that contains an array, when the property name is made of mulitple parts, **or when the property name contains characters that are not otherwise valid** (e.g. from json_decode() or SimpleXML).

Comment: I've tryed, nothing get. I''ve edit the output in the question

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$obj->getAttributeValue("22");
```

Please post the error if it  doesn't work

Comment: $pri = Cloud_printer::all();
        foreach($pri as $v)
        {

            Log::info($v->getAttributeValue("22"));
        }        production.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAttributeValue()'

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `getAttributeValue` is a function of an Eloquent model. What **version** of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Also could you post the output of `dd($pri)`?

Comment: check the question

Comment: Looks like Cloud_Printer is not an Eloquent model. It seems to be a custom class. Please post the code of this class

Comment: getAttribute works here, just like nvisser's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354778/6521116 but get empty value.

Comment: @KrisRoofe post the Cloud_Printer class code. I think it may be a problem in the class

Comment: Paras you check the question now. Thanks for you time and impatience.

Comment: `class Test extends Eloquent` doesn't make sense. Please post the actual code snippet. Posting test snippets wont help you. There's no Eloquent class, it should be `class Test extends Model` where Model refers to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: If you post the actual code, we can help. Otherwise, there's no way anyone can help you

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$col = '22';
$res = $obj->{$col};
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: I've tryed, nothing get. I''ve edit the output in the question

Answer (score 3):

if you always know the name is 22, you can do this.

```
 $myfield = 22;
 dd($obj->$myfield);
```

I tested it and it returns the value in the 22 field correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use model attribute $maps to give your troublesome column a different name. Try

```
$maps = ['22' => 'twentytwo'];

$hidden = ['22'];

$appends = ['twentytwo'];
```

Then with your model instance

```
echo $model->twentytwo;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr= Tablename::where('id', 1)->lists('22', 'id')->toArray();
$result = $arr[1];

As 1 is the $id var. I tried it in my localhost and it works
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is similar to this:

[Hide number field from Eloquent model in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162545/hide-number-field-from-eloquent-model-in-laravel/30162980#30162980)

Presently this is not possible in Laravel as seen in this line of code located in `vendor\symfony\var-dumper\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner.php at line 74`.

```
if ($zval['zval_isref'] = $queue[$i][$k] === $cookie) {
   $zval['zval_hash'] = $v instanceof Stub ? spl_object_hash($v) : null;
}
```

Here is the hack.

```
if ($zval['zval_isref'] = (isset($queue[$i][$k])) ? ($queue[$i][$k] === $cookie) : false) {
   $zval['zval_hash'] = $v instanceof Stub ? spl_object_hash($v) : null;
}
```

Issue has been discussed here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8710

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [how can I use exists column with laravel model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42341096/3472948)

The same answer applies here; you can use `$model->getAttribute('22')` to get the value of a model attribute.

Comment: Nope here for the numbers;

Comment: it just get empty values, like : [2017-02-23 19:30:28] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-23 19:30:28] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-23 19:30:28] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-23 19:30:28] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-23 19:30:28] production.INFO:  [] []
[2017-02-23 19:30:28] production.INFO:  [] []

Answer (score 1):

Try to use where:
`Tablename::where('22','=','value')->first();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$table = Tablename::get();

foreach ($table as $value){
   echo $value->22 // Getting column 22 from table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a question from years ago but hope someone find this helpful, if you have a database table column name set to 'Numbers' or Integer, you can fetch its data like this;

in your controller example:

```
$your-table = users::all(); //or use find etc.. 

//then loop

foreach ($your-table as $key)
{

 return $key['1']; <br><br>//['1'] is my db column name that is set to integer

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck)

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('22');

$plucked->all();
```