# how can I use exists column with laravel model

Tags: php, eloquent, exists, laravel-5.4

I have a column in my database called `exists`, but when I try to use

```
$model->exists
```

Laravel checks if the record  exists rater return the value of exists.

Is their any way to tell Laravel not to do this on that particular model?

Comment: check it once https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-exists-clauses

Comment: Perhaps consider changing your column name so that it doesn't clash, which will also prevent a lot of confusion in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested earlier, renaming your column would be a good idea, because it's a reserved keyword in most database servers.

To answer your question though, you can use `$model->getAttribute('exists')` to get the value of a model attribute.

[Source](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this as well; set a variable to the name of your field, then access it this way:

`$fieldname = 'exists';
$model->$fieldname;`