# MySQL table column name beginning with a number produce error while select query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my Table structure,

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_business` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `8a` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I trying to get data by select query,

```
SELECT * FROM wp_business;
```

I got the result but when I try to access the " 8a " column, getting an error.

```
$table_results[0]->8a;
```

Error:

> [09-Dec-2019 16:38:20 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '8' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in details.php on line 93

Comment: what is the result you get if you put $table_results[0]['8a']

Comment: It is best to give columns specific names. That way, it's easier to debug and keep track of what does what.

Answer (score 1):

Try variable parsing.

```
$table_results[0]-> {8a};
```

Or better way is to try to rename the column name in your SELECT query

```
SELECT `8a` as eightA FROM wp_business;
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get field (variable) name '8a' of a class object in PHP the way you try.

On the other hand, this is not a typical (but legal) way to specify a field starting with digit in MySQL. Same with PHP classes. So there are several alternatives to fix:

1. Change `8a` to something else starting with letter.
2. Specify array instead of object in PHP routine for MySQL result set.
3. Specify explicitly `SELECT ..., 8a as v8a, ...`
4. Use `$table_results[0]->{'8a'};`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions have already been provided for the same problem - [laravel how to access column with number name of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711470/laravel-how-to-access-column-with-number-name-of-a-table)